# How to parse "2021-11-20+01:00" formatted date string to ZonedDateTime - error

Tags: java, parsing, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

How to parse "2021-11-20+01:00" formatted date to `ZonedDateTime`? I'm trying like:

```
String value = "2021-11-20+01:00";
ZonedDateTime zDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddxxx"));
```

But getting this strange error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-11-20+01:00' could
> not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor:
> {OffsetSeconds=3600},ISO resolved to 2021-11-20 of type
> java.time.format.Parsed

> ...Unsupported field: InstantSeconds...

Any suggestions? This time format is used by [European VIES VAT ID checking system](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/technicalInformation.html) when receiving XML (SOAP) response: `<requestDate>2021-11-20+01:00</requestDate>`. The same error with `OffsetDateTime`..

Interesting thing is that Javadoc says "Three letters (x) outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'". So why above pattern is not working?

Tried also this one - the same error:

```
ZonedDateTime zDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
```

Complete error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-11-20 +01:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=3600},ISO resolved to 2021-11-20 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at javaapplication5.JavaApplication5.checkVATatVIES(JavaApplication5.java:162)
    at javaapplication5.JavaApplication5.main(JavaApplication5.java:65)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=3600},ISO resolved to 2021-11-20 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:235)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=3600},ISO resolved to 2021-11-20 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:378)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:365)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:203)
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:373)
    ... 6 more
```

Using OpenJDK 11.

Comment: By definition, a LocalDateTime is a date and time with no offset defined.  You probably want to use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead of LocalDateTime.

Comment: What is the time of that string?

Comment: No time used, just date 2021-11-20, and it is +1 hour GMT.

Comment: Updated question - problem still exists..

Comment: I have revised the question after those votes, so I hope close-votes will be retracted.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Java type consisting of only a date and a timezone.  ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime contain, as their names imply, both a date and a time.  So you need to create a formatter that will assume a default time of day:

```
String value = "2021-11-20+01:00";

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.appendPattern("yyyy-MM-ddxxx");
builder.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();

ZonedDateTime zDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
```

Of course, the hour of day can be any value you choose:  `12` to represent noon, for example.  But it has to be something valid.

Comment: This is the correct way. Instead of writing a format pattern I suggest using the built-in [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE); `builder.append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);`

Comment: Thanks for parseDefaulting method. This was the only way how to parse Instant without a time specification which throws Unsupported field: InstantSeconds.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.OffsetDate.parse( "2021-11-20+01:00" )
```

## `org.threeten.extra.OffsetDate`

The *java.time* classes built into Java do not offer a class for the idea of a date combined with an offset. So your parse attempts make no sense.

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/)  project aims at supplementing the functionality of *java.time*. It includes the [`OffsetDate`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/OffsetDate.html) class for your particular need. Add the library to your project.

```
String input = "2021-11-20+01:00" ;
OffsetDate od = OffsetDate.parse( input ) ;
```

From that `OffsetDate` object you can obtain either the `LocalDate` part or the `ZoneOffset` part. And you can determine other date-time values such as adding a time-of-day to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

You commented:

> if I make a request at 21th at 00:30 AM, I would get the response containing date of 20th.. because our time is UTC+2, and their time is UTC+1

As an aside, a tip: I suggest making a habit of using fully-formed offsets of hour with padding zero, and with minute too. While allowed by various standards, I have seen multiple libraries that fail when abbreviated. So I recommend “+02:00” rather than “UTC+2”.

Here is some example code demonstrating the scenario you describe. We use the time zone of `Africa/Brazzaville` because it has an offset of +01:00 at that moment, and we use `Europe/Kaliningrad` for its offset then of +02:00.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.NOVEMBER , 21 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 0 , 30 );
ZoneId zKaliningrad = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Kaliningrad" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKaliningrad = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , zKaliningrad );

ZoneId zBrazzaville = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Brazzaville" );
ZonedDateTime zdtBrazzaville = zdtKaliningrad.withZoneSameInstant( zBrazzaville );

OffsetDate od = OffsetDate.from( zdtBrazzaville );

OffsetDateTime odt = od.atTime( LocalTime.MIN );
ZonedDateTime asSeenInKaliningrad = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zKaliningrad );
```

When run.

```
zdtKaliningrad = 2021-11-21T00:30+02:00[Europe/Kaliningrad]
zdtBrazzaville = 2021-11-20T23:30+01:00[Africa/Brazzaville]
od = 2021-11-20+01:00
odt = 2021-11-20T00:00+01:00
asSeenInKaliningrad = 2021-11-20T01:00+02:00[Europe/Kaliningrad]
```

---

Personally, I question the practical value of the concept of date-with-offset, but that is beside the point of your Question.

Working in specific time zones is usually less problematic than working with mere offsets.

I would argue that it makes more sense to track a date-with-zone as a moment, the point on the timeline when the day begins, along with the named time zone rather than an offset.

```java
String result = 
    LocalDate
        .of( 2021 , 11 , 20 )
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Brazzaville" ) )
        .toString() 
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jWKGEl).

> 2021-11-20T00:00+01:00[Africa/Brazzaville]

For data exchange of text representing a single day, I would recommend transmitting this string `2021-11-20T00:00+01:00[Africa/Brazzaville]` in its format that extends [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

Comment: The benefit is minimal, but for example if I make a request at 21th at 00:30 AM, I would get the response containing date of 20th.. because our time is UTC+2, and their time is UTC+1.. 1 hour difference - but I see it is making quite a big problems to Java.... :)

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis I would argue that it makes more sense to track a date-with-zone as a moment, the point on the timeline when the day begins, along with the named time zone rather than an offset. Ex: `LocalDate.of( 2021 , 11 , 20 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Brazzaville" ) )`

Answer (score -2):

You can specify ur pattern by yourself as String like this:

```
String str = "2021-11-20+01:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm");
LocalDateTime date= LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was with pattern.. Now `LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm"));` is working perfectly.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Is that time or an offset?

Comment: That is an offset +1 of GMT. Hmm..

Comment: Updated question - perhaps this answer also should be modified.. Thanks.